# Why does I get this magige

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get this error when I try to do `mysqli_num_rows()`

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search.php on line 13
>       There are no results matching your search

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE a_title LIKE '%$search%' OR a_text LIKE '%$search%' OR a_author LIKE '%$search%' OR a_date LIKE '%$search%";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php have a look on return values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row()/mysql\_num\_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc)

Comment: Looks like your query is failing. You should add some proper error handling to see why.

Comment: Note that mysqli_real_escape_string is not safe without setting the defualt charset it's in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) "Security: the default character set

The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function mysqli_set_charset() " .. or using the better option prepared statements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is very likey that your query has failed. In this case `mysqli_query` returns a boolean false value instead of a mysqli_result, as explained in the [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

You need to check for errors after running your query, like :

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

By looking at your query I see that you are missing a final single quote  `'` (could be a typo as well) :

```
$sql = 
    "SELECT * 
     FROM posts 
     WHERE 
         a_title LIKE '%$search%' 
         OR a_text LIKE '%$search%'
         OR a_author LIKE '%$search%'
         OR a_date LIKE '%$search%";
```

To avoid that, and protect yourself against sql injection, you should use bind parameters.